# Can a store take my bag when it contains both my and their property?

Tags: criminal-law, theft

I've had my bag snatched from me before I've even got anywhere near till point (cash register). They told me to leave because I'm barred. They won't let me in to get my bag, and they still have it. How can I get my property back?

Comment: I frequently take a shopping bag into a store to hold items I have selected, before I reach the point of payment. Doing so is not theft, if there is no attempt to conceal them or pretend that thy are mine. Indeed many stores sell or provide bags for this purpose. The question does not presently make the circumstances clear. In any case, the store cannot lawfully retain the property of an accused thief, nor even of a convicted one.

Comment: Could the store employees  have reasonably believed that this was an attempt at shoplifting? Did they say it was?  Did you ask for the return of your property? Did you notify law enforcement?

Answer (score 6):

### Go to the police

Taking someone’s property with the intention of permanently depriving them of it is stealing.

Ask a nice police officer to accompany you to the store to help you sort it out.